# Continuous Running Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-scraping

I have written a `Web Scraper` just in a plain ole `ASP.Net/C#` website. It works great, does exactly what I need it to do, but there is one small problem.

I would like it to run twice a day. All of the code is in place, but I am unable to find a solution to get it to run twice a day (10AM and 10PM).

Is a web service a solution? Can you set those to run at scheduled times?

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming your existing website just runs on launch, why not add a scheduled task? http://superuser.com/questions/447368/set-windows-scheduler-to-open-a-webpage-or-the-bookmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "application" is a web application and not a Windows executable you can still use Windows Task Scheduler to open your web page on a scheduled basis.

Specify the Action as "Start a Program" and specify the Program/Script as IE: "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

Enter the URL to your web page as the argument and click ok.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On linux based systems you typically use a *cronjob* for this. On windows based systems you can use a *[scheduled task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx)*.

Here is the documentation on how you would [create a scheduled task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx).

From the command line:

> ```
> schtasks /Create [/S <system> [/U <username> [/P [<password>]]]]
> [/RU <username> [/RP <password>]] /SC <schedule> [/MO <modifier>] [/D <day>]
> [/M <months>] [/I <idletime>] /TN <taskname> /TR <taskrun> [/ST <starttime>]
> [/RI <interval>] [ {/ET <endtime> | /DU <duration>} [/K] [/XML <xmlfile>] [/V1]]
> [/SD <startdate>] [/ED <enddate>] [/IT] [/Z] [/F]
> ```

More details about the paramters can be found in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So in your example you would need to specify the first task with `schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Your TaskName" /TR "Path and Executable to be run" /ST 10:00` and the second task with `schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "Your TaskName" /TR "Path and Executable to be run" /ST 22:00`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, you can. 
I have made use of Nuget Packages([Quartz.Net Scheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/) or [FluentScheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentScheduler/)) for this purpose, in Asp.Net websites.
Both has a lot of options available for scheduling based on day/time/month etc.
Only thing is that you need to make sure the AppPool doesn't recycle periodically, which is the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows, use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule to run your application twice a day.